# Join TEXT and VARCHAR columns together in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, types, inner-join

I have the following query and error message:

```
WITH full_table AS (
    SELECT TRANSACTION_ID AS Transaction,USER_ID AS USER, TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP, ORDER_LINE_ITEM, TIME_TAKEN, QUANTITY, TIME_STANDARD, transactions_department.DEPARTMENT, (TIME_STANDARD*QUANTITY) AS NORMALIZED_TIME_STANDARD
    FROM pivoted_standards
    INNER JOIN 
    transactions_department 
    ON 
    pivoted_standards.DEPARTMENT = transactions_department.DEPARTMENT
    ORDER BY
    USER, TIMESTAMP, ORDER_LINE_ITEM
) SELECT * FROM full_table
```

Error:

```
Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='
```

This error is talking about where I joined pivoted_standards.DEPARTMENT = transactions_department.DEPARTMENT. Both of these have the same collation, but one is VARCHAR while the other is text. How can I join them together? Is it possible to do that in this query?

Comment: Do those table really have the same collation? If so, why does the error message show otherwise? How about you show us the table structure by running `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;` for both tables and post it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to workaround that by adding `COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci` on `transactions_department.DEPARTMENT` like this:

```
WITH full_table AS (
    SELECT TRANSACTION_ID AS Transaction,USER_ID AS USER, TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP, ORDER_LINE_ITEM, TIME_TAKEN, QUANTITY, TIME_STANDARD, transactions_department.DEPARTMENT, (TIME_STANDARD*QUANTITY) AS NORMALIZED_TIME_STANDARD
    FROM pivoted_standards
    INNER JOIN 
    transactions_department 
    ON
    pivoted_standards.DEPARTMENT = transactions_department.DEPARTMENT COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci
    ORDER BY                                                      /*here ^^^^^ */
    USER, TIMESTAMP, ORDER_LINE_ITEM
) SELECT * FROM full_table;
```

[Here's a fiddle example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/opnj5TnLELWaH9VGcqcifR/0)

However, this is not a recommended long-term solution. I know that there are reasons why people need to have different collation so consider using something like `dept_id` with `INT` datatype and join the tables with different collation using that instead.

[Example fiddle using INT datatype for join](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/opnj5TnLELWaH9VGcqcifR/1)